# how to select a row on a table based on a condition in another row of another table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to show only the rows from one table that meet a certain condition in another table. Example on the `controller`:

```
        using(inventarioEntitiesDBA dc = new inventarioEntitiesDBA())
        {
            ProductandBodViewModel finalitem = new ProductandBodViewModel();

            var m_List = dc.showcase.Where(x => x.prod_on_showcase > 0).ToList();
        }
```

With the code above it's possible to display only the items that meets the condition, `prod_on_showcase > 0`. The `ProductandBodViewModel` is a model that I created to show two models on a same view.

The `ProductandBodViewModel` model:

```
public class ProductandBodViewModel
{
    public List<inventory> inventory { get; set; }

    public List<showcase> showcase { get; set; }
}
```

According to this condition (`prod_on_showcase > 0`) I want to show other information that is related to the table `showcase` table.

The model of the `showcase` table:

```
public class showcaseViewModel
{
    public int id_inventory { get; set; }
    
    public int prod_on_showcase { get; set; }
}
```

The model of the `inventory` table:

```
public partial class inventory
{
    public int id_inventory { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> prod_on_inventory { get; set; }
    public string prod_code { get; set; }
}
```

The relation between the tables is the `id_inventory` field.

In this case, the items displayed for the `showcase` table are 3, so the `inventory` table must also display 3 items.
With the code below it's possible to display info of the table `showcase` that meets the condition but with the other table (`inventory`) only display the first element that it's found according to the condition `prod_on_showcase > 0`.

```
using(inventarioEntitiesDBA dc = new inventarioEntitiesDBA())
{
    ProductandBodViewModel finalitem = new ProductandBodViewModel();

    var m_List = dc.showcase.Where(x => x.prod_on_showcase > 0).ToList();

    var m_Each = dc.showcase.Where(e => e.prod_on_showcase > 0).Count();

    for(int i = 0; i < m_Each; i++)
    {
        var prodEach = dc.inventory.Where(x => x.prod_on_showcase > 0).FirstOrDefault();

        var b = dc.inventory.Where(a => a.id_inventory == prodEach.id_inventory).ToList();

        finalitem.bod = b;
    }

    finalitem.showcase = m_List;

    return View(finalitem);                
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking `var prodEach = dc.inventory.Where(x => x.prod_on_showcase > 0).FirstOrDefault();` to always return the First(or default) element in the array.

Linq's `SelectMany` is useful for what you're trying to do.

````
using(inventarioEntitiesDBA dc = new inventarioEntitiesDBA())
{
    ProductandBodViewModel finalitem = new ProductandBodViewModel();

    var m_List = dc.showcase.Where(x => x. > 0).ToList();

    var m_List = showcase.Where(x => x.prod_on_showcase > 0).ToList();

    finalitem.showcase = m_List.SelectMany(prodEach
        => dc.inventory.Where(a => a.id_inventory == prodEach.id_inventory)

    finalitem.showcase = m_List;

    return View(finalitem);                
 }```
````

Comment: Your suggestion works for me, thanks, all I had to do was add the `ToList()` method to the end of the line. So it would be like this:

`finalitem.inventory = m_List.SelectMany(prodEach => dc.inventory.Where(a => a.id_inventory == prodEach.id_inventory)).ToList();`